# Can't run new activity from onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm having trouble starting my mainActivity after I have gotten a response from a httpUrlConnection. 
Here is my onPostExecute method

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        serv.httphelper.handleResults(result);

    }
```

In the method handleResult() im handling the response code. If the response code is 200 i want to run a new method inside my loginActivity class

```
public void handleResults(String[] result) {

    status = result[0].toString();
    instructions = result[1].toString();
    jsonString = result[2];

    Log.d("DEBUG", status);

    if (status.equals("200")) {
        serv.loginActivity.proceed();

    } else if (status.equals("400")) {
        serv.loginActivity.loginError();

    } else if (status.equals("401")) {
        serv.loginActivity.loginError();

    }

}
```

When i try to start a new activity from the proceed() method i get a nullpointerexception

```
    public void proceed(){
    startActivity(new Intent (LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    Log.d("TEST", "Proceed success");


}
```

My service class for anyone wondering:

```
public class Service {

public static HttpHelper httphelper = new HttpHelper();
public static HttpConnect conn = new HttpConnect();
public static LoginActivity loginActivity = new LoginActivity();
```

}

And here is my logCat:
[image: LogCat]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your AsyncTask is in which Activity? and what is 'serv'?

Comment: My AsyncTask is in a class for itself, called HttpConnect and serv is just a class i made to instanciate new class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is when you start the activity at the line:

```
startActivity(new Intent (LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
```

Well, you creates an intent that tries to get to `LoginActivity.this` which probably does not exists!
Instead of this, you have to give an instance of a real activity that is currently running.

A solution that I can suggest you is to pass to `proceed()` the instance of the currently running activity and put it instead of `LoginActivity.this`.
In case you don't have a current activity, try to put your application's context instead and add it a flag of a new task.

Comment: Okay so after 2 hours of trying different solutions i finally solved my problem. I had to pass the application context just as you said. Thanks alot!